# Can't find MTU field configuration in my Router settings?

Tags: mtu

I have a HUMAX router in my house and I'm trying to configure the proper MTU size for my newtwork.

The problem is that when i login in the routers admin panel, i can't find the MTU setting.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnZir.png)

Comment: That is something you shouldn't mess with unless you really, really know what you are doing.

Comment: (Besides, changing the Wi-Fi MTU probably won't help with the real problem you had...)

Comment: are you sure? EVERYWHERE i look it tells me i should change my MTU in order to fix my internet speed: https://www.cnet.com/news/tip-increase-internet-speed-by-manipulating-mtu-size/

Comment: MTU size would be what your router hands off to your modem/ISP, nothing to do with "wireless". Look in Basic or Advanced at the WAN settings, but ONLY if you have tested it thoroughly and know what it should be. It is very easy to test with simple PING commands, Google can get you directions quickly. That said, my company installs 150 routers per year all across the country, can't recall many instance where that needs to be changed in the last 5 years, twice maybe. It is not normal. The article you linked is 10 years old and not exactly relevant to most ISP's anymore.

Comment: Oh, and only test MTU on a wired interface, testing on a WiFi interface may not give proper results for testing out to the ISP. It should almost always be 1500 bytes in normal home internet.